# Gradle sync failed : Connection refused error in android 2.3

Tags: android

I have created a project with support of mobile and auto. And try to build the project but it gives the error Gradle sync failed Connection refused .

In SDK update sites, I am not able to get the path of android repository.

How to resolve this problem?

Please Help...

Answer (score 5):

To get a more detailed answer, you should write down the problem in detail.

If it exists, you should check `build.gradle` and `library/build.gradle` files in the libraries you have added as a project module `compile project(path: ':XX')`

And check in `settings.grade` that `project(':XX').projectDir = new File('../XXXX/library')` and check the versions of your `com.android.support:support-` libraries.